# Mysql ambiguous column

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a query like this

```
 select id, company_id, name, type, number
 from people as p
 inner join company c on c.id = p.company_id
 limit 10
```

and in here both tables have name column and `name` would be ambiguous.

is there a way to not prefix it to `p.name` and use the select part as it is and not prefix it all?

is there a way to tell mysql that if any ambiguous column found, use main tables columns??

Comment: No. You've got to tell the database which column you want.

Comment: Hmmm, why? I guess you could create a temp table, rename the column, then join the temp table... but again, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have have no choice but to specify it with table name. See this note in the **[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)**. Last line is important for this question.

> You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly. You can refer to a column as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or db_name.tbl_name.col_name. You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference unless the reference would be ambiguous.

Then this one is more specific and uses the term '**must**'.

> You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference in a statement unless the reference would be ambiguous. Suppose that tables t1 and t2 each contain a column c, and you retrieve c in a SELECT statement that uses both t1 and t2. In this case, c is ambiguous because it is not unique among the tables used in the statement. You must qualify it with a table name as t1.c or t2.c to indicate which table you mean. Similarly, to retrieve from a table t in database db1 and from a table t in database db2 in the same statement, you must refer to columns in those tables as db1.t.col_name and db2.t.col_name.

**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)**